# Cannot find event from looking at ZfcUser User Mapper code

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfcuser, zend-framework3

I was reading the `UserMapper` code from the `ZfcUser Zend Framework Module`  because i thought i could get a general concept of using zends auth system before i build out mine and was curious about something.

In it ([click here](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/1.x/src/ZfcUser/Mapper/User.php)), on line 19, we have the following code:

```
$this->getEventManager()->trigger('find', $this, array('entity' => $entity));
```

**I really want to know where i can find the "find" event thats being triggered or is it a placeholder for a possible find event in the future**

I looked at the Module file and a few others and cannot locate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zfcuser` is a very complete module with lot of features that in normal basic authen you wouldn't need. These features include several event that `ZfcUser` trigger but it don't need it, it is just here in case a user need to perform a specific action on this event.

More, `ZfcUser`can be used with other modules as [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) and [roleuserbridge](https://github.com/darkmatus/roleuserbridge) to provide more functionnality (acl and user role management...), and these third-party modules can use the events triggered by `ZfcUser`.

For example, you want to log every user authentication, you can use the `authenticate` event this way in your `onBootstrap()` method: (example from [here](http://circlical.com/blog/2013/7/5/capturing-auth-events-with-zfcuser)):

```
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$zfcAuthEvents = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain')->getEventManager();

$zfcAuthEvents->attach( 'authenticate', function( $authEvent ) use( $sm ){
    try {
        $remote     = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;
        $remote->setUseProxy( true );

        $mapper     =  $sm->get( 'auth_log_mapper' );
        $log_entity = new \FooUser\Entity\UserAuthenticationLog;
        $log_entity->populate(
                array(
               'user_id'       => $authEvent->getIdentity(),
                'auth_time'     => new \DateTime( "now" ),
                'ip_address'    => $remote->getIpAddress()
            )
        );

        $mapper->save( $log_entity );
        return true;
    } catch( \Exception $x ) {
        // handle it
    }
});
```

So the `find` event may not be usefull for `ZfcUser`, it is not a placeholder for a future development of this module, it is a hook for you, if you need to do something when a user is found in the users repository...